# Setting up the triple integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let W be the region $\{(x,y,z) | |x|\le 1, |y| \le 1, z\ge 0 \text{ and } x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1\}$. I need to find appropriate limits of the following integral $$ \iiint_W f = \int^b_a \int^{\phi_2(x)}_{\phi_1(x)} \int^{\psi_1(x,y)}_{\psi_2(x,y)} f(x,y,z) \,dz\,dy\,dx$$

So along with the upper half hemisphere we also have the square of unit 1, And since the circle of radius 1 is always inside the square of unit 1, it won't affect the limits. So I think, the limits would be $$ \int^1_{-1} \int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}_0 f\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
Am I correct?

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: Thanks for confirming.